# How to take the sum of only even and odd numbers? C#

Tags: c#

When the user enters numbers, say 3 and 7, the program adds all of the number in between and the numbers the user entered. Now I need to make it add only the even and odds in between the numbers. This is what I have so far:

```
static void Exercise1()
    {
        int min;
        int max;
        int sum = 0;
        int odd = 0;
        int even = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter minimum integer: ");
        min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter maximum integer: ");
        max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
       //Sum of all
        Console.Write("All: ");
         for (int x = min; x <= max; x++)
            {
                Console.Write(min);
                min++;
                Console.Write(" + ");
                sum += x;
            }
         Console.Write("= ");
         Console.Write(sum + "\n");

        //Odd Numbers
         Console.Write("Odd: ");
         for (int x = min; x <= max; x++)
         {
             if (min % 2 != 0)
             {
                 Console.Write(min);
                 min++;
                 Console.Write(" + ");
                 odd += x;
             }

         }
         Console.Write("= ");
         Console.Write(odd + "\n");

        //Even Numbers
         Console.Write("Even: ");
         for (int x = min; x <= max; x++)
         {

             if (min % 2 == 0)
             {
                 Console.Write(min);
                 min++;
                 Console.Write(" + ");
                 even += x;
             }   

         }
         Console.Write("= ");
         Console.Write(even + "\n");

        }
```

I can find the sum of all the numbers but what I have tried here is the extent of my knowledge. I have hit a dead end.

Comment: You're method for dealing with odd and even numbers are almost exactly the same. This is a sign you should pull them out into a function with a parameter or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing the roles of `x` and `min`. `min` is entered by the user and serves as the starting point for your method; you shouldn't be changing it. However, you change `min` during each iteration of your `for` loops. So first of all, remove `min++` from all three of your `for` loops.
`x` is a variable that changes as your find the sums. So instead of Writing the value of `min` to console (this value should be constant, you are really trying to find out what the value of `x` is...  So, change your `Console.Write(min)` to `Console.Write(x)`

Also change your `if`-statement from

```
 if (min % 2 != 0)
```

to

```
 if (x % 2 != 0)
```

You can brush up on the `for`-loop (and other) control statements by reading [this lesson](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson04) or watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IuTDC7FkPRI).

Comment: Dude thank you so much I have been trying for so long with this.

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved the issue, please consider accepting the answer, and be sure to check into those resources. I think they'll help you tackle the loop constructs as you move forward.

Answer (score 3):

You're doing `min++` within the loops, which means `min` is not what it should be. It is sometimes a reasonable micro-optimisation to do `++min` and not have an `x` at all, but only if you're never going to need that value again.

You could speed things up by skipping `x += 2` in each loop once you've found the odd (or even, accordingly), but speed things even more so by having one loop:

```
int sum = 0;
int odd = 0;
int even = 0;
for (int x = min; x <= max; x++)
{
    sum += x;
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        even += x;
    else
        odd += x;
}
```

However you can do much better with a bit of mathematical thinking on it.

∑[x, y] = (y - x + 1)(y + x)/2

E.g. from `5` to `9` is `5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9` = `35` and also is `(9 - 5 + 1) * (5 + 9) / 2` = `35`.

So to find the sum you don't need a loop, you need:

```
int sum = (max - min + 1) * (max + min) / 2;
```

This would make a big difference in speed if `min` was `-1024` and `max` was `8980` because you can just do this calculation and get `39799890` rather than having to loop through 10005 different values.

Similarly if you find the min even number (`minEven = min % 2 == 0 ? min : min + 1`) and the max even number (`maxEven = max % 2 == 0 ? max : max - 1`) then you can find the sum of evens with:

```
int sumEven = ((maxEven - minEven) / 2 + 1) * (maxEven + minEven) / 2;
```

And indeed the exact same formula works for odd:

```
int sumOdd = ((maxOdd - minOdd) / 2 + 1) * (maxOdd + minOdd) / 2;
```

There, there's no need to do any looping at all, and your Θ(n) approach can be replaced with a Θ(1) approach.

Comment: (The general form of the formula is that for any sequence that increases at the same rate, then the sum is `N * (first + last) / 2` were `N` is the number of elements in the sequence).

Comment: I personally love this approach and it's much more efficient. I think the real issue of the OP stems from a misunderstanding of the `for`-loop control structure. Nonetheless, this definitely solves the present issue. Well done!

Comment: @AustinD I did start off by addressing the problem with the for loop in the first sentence and the inefficiency of doing three loops rather than one in the next, before coming to the constant-time approach one would use in real code, because understanding why the loop didn't work is indeed the most important for general programming understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that more as a compliment and to reiterate to the OP the core issue. I thought your answer was excellent!

Comment: Ah, darn the small space given in comments. I just meant to say in agreement, for the same reason, that while I'd always want to take a single-calculation approach when I can, the querent should definitely focus on understanding why the loop didn't work, and how to program good loops. Loops are bread-and-butter to programming languages like C#, finding a way to avoid them and get a quicker answer come up much more rarely.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way worth looking at:

```
static void Exercise1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter minimum integer: ");
    int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter maximum integer: ");
    int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    IEnumerable<int> all = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1);
    IEnumerable<int> odds = all.Where(n => n % 2 == 1);
    IEnumerable<int> evens = all.Where(n => n % 2 == 0);

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("All: {0} = {1}", String.Join(" + ", all), all.Sum()));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Odd: {0} = {1}", String.Join(" + ", odds), odds.Sum()));
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Even: {0} = {1}", String.Join(" + ", evens), evens.Sum()));
}
```

That should give you something to thing about.